how to add a Managed Module in IIS10 of Win2019?
I can add a Managed Module at IIS7 of Win2012 as below capture.
(https://i.sstatic.net/s1JPJ.png)
but not found this command at IIS10 of Win2019.
I wonder to know how to add a Managed Module in IIS10 of Win2019?
I try to add the config item in the web.config, but it doesn't work.

To add managed module in iis first make sure you have installed the iis .net 4.7 framework with .NET Extensibility. after that close and reopen iis server you can find the module mapping inside Modules.
You can also add it in web.config file directly:
    <system.webServer>
      <modules>
         <add name="Module-Name" type="Namespace.ClassName, AssemblyName" />
      </modules>
   </system.webServer>

